# Question about Azure Load Balancer/Azure Traffic Manager

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, azure-load-balancer, azure-traffic-manager

If one application have Azure serviceBus, EventHub in diff Azure Namesapces, web application and also other azure services (eg: cognitive services). can these be accessed with one URL by using Gateway or Load balancer or traffic manager or any other option ?

My problem is - if we have diff namesapces, we need to whitelist every time when there is new Namespaces and it could so too much of a work. so wondering if we can have one common DNS/URL that would make life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Today, Service Bus and Event Hubs don't support any sort of network gateway. This is due to fact that namespace in the connection string used for authorization purpose at the service side.

Comment: Thank you, Serkant! for information. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit of context to Serkant's statement, support for this scenario is something that is on our roadmap, and hopefully in the near term.  Unfortunately,  I don't have a date to share currently.  The work is being tracked [[here]](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12555) should you wish to keep an eye on it.

Comment: Thank you, Jesse! I will keep eye on tracking ticket.